# Suppose the total cost, TC, is the sum of two parts of costs

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the total cost, TC, is the sum of two parts of costs, C-A and C-B. Suppose both C-A and C-B are twice-differentiable in a variable s. Suppose further that C-A increases in s, and C-B decreases in s.
a)  Find the first order condition if you are to choose s to minimize the total cost, TC. Graph the minimization.
b)  Suppose C-A increases in a parameter, α, but the slope of C-A with respect to s does not depend on α. Suppose also C-B does not depend on α. How does an increase in the value of α affect the optimized s?  Graph the changes.
c)  Suppose both C-A and the slope of C-A with respect to s increase in α. Suppose also C-B does not depend on α. How does an increase in the value of α affect the optimized s?  Graph the changes.

Comment: And your thoughts on this are.....?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. This question with about $10$ parts is not likely to get an answer.

Comment: Also, avoid "walls of text". Try formatting your answer to be easier to read.